# jQuery mobile change select value by script fail (nothing happens)

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm desperately trying to change the option value in of a select at pageshow and it does nothing.
I don't know how to change it

```
<select name="sliderAutoConnect" id="sliderAutoConnect" data-role="slider">
      <option value="1">Off</option>
      <option value="2">On</option>
</select>
```

and the script :

```
$("#sliderAutoConnect option[value=2]").attr('selected', 'selected');
$('#sliderAutoConnect').selectmenu('refresh');
```

Comment: I added the code sample in the body of the question

Comment: Oh ok thank you give me a moment to revise my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refresh the slider widget instead of selectmenu. Try this instead:

```
$('#sliderAutoConnect').slider('refresh');
```

Everything else worked for me when i tested it. I just changed that one line.